# sparse matrices: fastest way to determine if value is null or not?

Tags: c++, eigen

With Eigen: given a large sparse matrix, what would be the quickest way to determine if a value at a given position is null or not ?

It must be said that I use this sparse matrix implementation to store **non-numeric values**. It's related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37682868/).

At present, what I have is (with `T` my data type):

```
Eigen::SparseMatrix<T> mat(n,n); // n could be 1000, 10000, ...

// fill
T e1( /* some values */ );
mat.insert( 3, 4 ) = e1;
...
```

Checking is done with:

```
T elem = mat.coeff( row, col );
if( elem == T() ) // use default constructor
    std::cout << "empty !\n";
```

But this doesn't satisfy me, as it implies both a copy operation and a deep comparison operator. What I would like could be something like:

```
if( mat.isNull( row, col ) )
    std::cout << "empty !\n";
```

Is there a way I can do this ? Or fetch a pointer that return `nullptr` if empty?
I checked [Tutorial pages](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialSparse.html), [quick ref](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__SparseQuickRefPage.html) and [relevant manual pages](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1SparseMatrix.html) but didn't find anything.

If this appears to be not possible, then I am thinking about wrapping it in a class along with a map holding all the filled positions. That way I could quickly find out if a given row,col has a value.

Addendum: I have Eigen 3.2 but could switch to 3.3 if required.

**Edit**: the linked question asks how to get a set of non-null elements. What I am asking for is  "how do I know if the value at (row,col) is null ?". Not a dupe AFAIK.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eigen Sparse Matrix get Indices of Nonzero Elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28854640/eigen-sparse-matrix-get-indices-of-nonzero-elements)

Comment: @timrau Really ? Could you please read again the other question and reconsider your flag. I am **not** asking about how to get a set of non-null values but how to know if a given (row,col) position holds a null value.

Comment: Snippet in my previous comment was wrong.

Comment: Ok, so what you are telling me is "you have to iterate through the non-null values". Still not a dupe to me, the other question is not formulated the same way, allthough it gives the way to iterate (which I already knew).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Derived from https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TutorialSparse.html , you can define the null checking function like

```
bool isNull(const Eigen::SparseMatrix<T>& mat, int row, int col)
{
    for (Eigen::SparseMatrix<T>::InnerIterator it(mat, col); it; ++it) {
        if (it.row() == row) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

This way you don't copy anything. You don't perform deep comparison either.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Yeah, that's probably the only solution without having to store indexes. I'll probably have to check which one is fastest, as it could still hold quite a number of values.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the number of elements per column, the most efficient solution might be to do a binary search the same way as [`coeffRef()`](https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/src/3215c06819b9/Eigen/src/SparseCore/SparseMatrix.h?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#SparseMatrix.h-198). You can in fact copy that function, replace all returns by `true` or `false` and integrate it into the `SparseMatrix` using the [plugin-mechanism](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicCustomizing_Plugins.html).

Most of the time it is inefficient to access individual elements of a sparse matrix, though.